# Use await only for 20 seconds

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am waiting for my promise to resolve in an async function using await but I want to wait for only 20 sec. If no response comes in that time (neither positive nor negative from the promise), I want to continue and display 'timeout'. How can I do this?

Comment: can you share the codes you already have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Promise.race`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race):

```
const promise1 = func();
const promise2 = new Promise((res, rej) => setTimeout(rej, 20000));

try { 
   await Promise.race([promise1, promise2]);
} catch (e) {
   // time out or func failed
}
```